# Can we freeze the columns in JQGRID?

Tags: html, jqgrid

Can we freeze the Columns in JQGRID.

Answer (score 2):

Since jqGrid 4.3.0 you can now freeze the first N columns of the grid, so that a horizontal scroll bar appears and they stay fixed (frozen) while you can still scroll the un-frozen columns.

- Wiki : [Setup and limitations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afrozencolumns&s%5B%5D=setfrozencolumns)
- Demo : [Frozen Columns](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/examples/functionality/frozen/default.php)

Answer (score 1):

This is only planned. You can vote for this feature at http://www.trirand.com/blog/.

Comment: I am using jqGrid and cannot really afford to wait for this feature to be implemented. Does anybody know of any available workarounds?